# Receiving error on json schema validation

Tags: aws-api-gateway, openapi, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm using the following schema to validate my json body payload however within api gateway I receive the error :

```
instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: 
 ["string"])]
```

Does anyone know what this means as I don't see how this relates to my schema?

schema:

```
components:
  schemas:

    submission:
      type: object
      required: [name, questions, metadata]
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        questions:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/questions'
        metadata:
          type: object
          required: [paymentSkipped]
          properties:
            paymentSkipped: bolean
      additionalProperties: false

    questions:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/questionobj'
      additionalProperties: false

    questionobj:
      type: object
      required: [category, question]
      properties:
        category:
          type: string
        question:
          type: string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON literal `null` is recognized as a separate type in JSON Schema.  If you want to allow strings *and* `null`, you need to include it in your `type` declaration:

```json
{
  "type": [ "string", "null" ]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Figured it out now turns out one of the json fields was null which  I didn't realise, used your snippet and all good